# track last change that occurred across rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

suppose I have a data frame that tracks changes in value across rows. If the value increases, the change is 'positive'. If the value decreases, the change is 'negative'. Otherwise, the change column says 'no change'

```
df = data.frame(sequence = 1:10, value = c(1,1,1, 2, 2,2,2,1,1,1), change = c('no change', 'no change', 'no change', 'positive', 'no change', 'no change', 'no change', 'negative', 'no change','no change'))
```

I want to create a new column that tracks the nature of the last change which occurred in the value column. in this case, the final data frame should look like this

```
df = data.frame(sequence = 1:10, value = c(1,1,1, 2, 2,2,2,1,1,1), change = c('no change', 'no change', 'no change', 'positive', 'no change', 'no change', 'no change', 'negative', 'no change','no change')), last_change = c('no change', 'no change', 'no change', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'positive', 'negative', 'negative', 'negative')
```

How can I go about doing this? This is sample data - my actual data contains 3 million rows. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by leveraging `data.table::rleid`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, last_change:=first(change), rleid(value)]
```

Output:

```
    sequence value    change last_change
       <int> <num>    <char>      <char>
 1:        1     1 no change   no change
 2:        2     1 no change   no change
 3:        3     1 no change   no change
 4:        4     2  positive    positive
 5:        5     2 no change    positive
 6:        6     2 no change    positive
 7:        7     2 no change    positive
 8:        8     1  negative    negative
 9:        9     1 no change    negative
10:       10     1 no change    negative
```

Answer (score 5):

A `dplyr` one-liner, without grouping (faster, see benchmark):

```r
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(last_change = change[x <- lag(value, default = 0) != value][cumsum(x)])
```

output

```r
   sequence value    change last_change
1         1     1 no change   no change
2         2     1 no change   no change
3         3     1 no change   no change
4         4     2  positive    positive
5         5     2 no change    positive
6         6     2 no change    positive
7         7     2 no change    positive
8         8     1  negative    negative
9         9     1 no change    negative
10       10     1 no change    negative
```

---

Since the question implies that this would be done on a large data set, I did a benchmark of the two solutions with dataframe with 1,000,000 rows:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df2 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(100000, df, simplify = FALSE))

microbenchmark(
   f1 = mutate(df2,
               last_change = change[x <- lag(value, default = 0) != value][cumsum(x)]),
   f2 = setDT(df2)[, last_change:=first(change), rleid(value)]
 )
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq      mean   median         uq       max neval
   f1  27.2198  34.2597  47.15247  39.8145   49.72065  155.3829   100
   f2 767.8063 908.2213 996.29603 964.0844 1019.84905 1595.0273   100
```

The first function (the one proposed here) is much faster, I am guessing because it does not perform any grouping.

---

**Explanation**

`x <- lag(value, default = 0) != value` gives a logical vector of whether the value is different from the previous one (length 10), then `change[]` gives the vector of the values of `change` when `x` is `TRUE` (length 3), and then `change[x][cumsum(x)]` gives the values of `change[x]` according to the pattern of `cumsum(x)` (length 10), which is basically the position of the latest changed value.

```r
(x <- with(df, lag(value, default = 0) != value))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

with(df, cumsum(x))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3

with(df, change[x])
#[1] "no change" "positive"  "negative" 

with(df, change[x][cumsum(x)])
#[1] "no change" "no change" "no change" "positive"  "positive"  "positive"  "positive" "negative"  "negative"  "negative"
```

Comment: thanks a lot! im trying to understand the code - is the cumsum(x) is giving the position of the last change? (which is determined by lag(value) not being equal to value

Comment: Exactly. See edit

Answer (score 4):

Using `base R` with `rle`

```
df$last_change <- with(df, ave(change, with(rle(value), 
    rep(seq_along(values), lengths)), FUN = function(x) x[1]))
```

-output

```
> df
   sequence value    change last_change
1         1     1 no change   no change
2         2     1 no change   no change
3         3     1 no change   no change
4         4     2  positive    positive
5         5     2 no change    positive
6         6     2 no change    positive
7         7     2 no change    positive
8         8     1  negative    negative
9         9     1 no change    negative
10       10     1 no change    negative
```